# Attempting to use custom binding in knockout.js ... getting an error ... where do I look

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

this is my JS

```
   function TheatreViewModel(theatre) {
        var self = this,
            initialData = theatre || Regal.userPrimaryTheatre || {},
            theatreServiceParams = {
                tmsId: initialData.TmsId,
                date: initialData.selectedDate || new Date()
            };

        self.TheatreName = initialData.TheatreName || '';
        self.PhoneNumber = initialData.PhoneNumber || '';
        self.selectedTheatreTms = initialData.TmsId;
        self.theatre = ko.observable();
        self.isLoading = ko.observable(false);
        self.selectedDate = ko.observable(initialData.selectedDate || new Date());

        self.filterFormats = [];

        self.selectedFormat = ko.observable(Regal.allFormatsFilterItem);
        self.filterFormats.push(Regal.allFormatsFilterItem);
        if (Regal.movieFormats) {
            var filtered = _.where(Regal.movieFormats, {
                Filterable: true
            });
            _.forEach(filtered, function (f) {
                f.enabled = ko.observable(false);
                self.filterFormats.push(f);
            });
        }

        self.addressText = ko.computed(function () {
            var theat = ko.unwrap(self.theatre);
            var addie;
            if (!theat || theat && !theat.Address1) {
                addie = initialData;
            } else {
                addie = theat;
            }

            return addie.Address1 + ', ' + addie.City + ' ' + addie.State + ' ' + addie.PostalCode;
        });

        self.mapEmbedUrl = ko.computed(function () {
            var a = self.addressText();
            return 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + encodeURI(a);
        });

        self.movies = ko.computed(function () {
            var thea = self.theatre(),
                mov = ko.unwrap((thea || {}).Movies),
                format = self.selectedFormat();

            if (format && format !== Regal.allFormatsFilterItem) {
                return _.filter(mov, function (m) {
                    return _.contains(_.pluck(m.formats(), 'Id'), format.Id);
                });
            }
            return mov;
        });

        self.getPerformances = function () {
            self.isLoading(true);
            Regal.loadTheatre(self.selectedDate(), self.selectedTheatreTms,
                function (data) {
                    self.isLoading(false);
                    if (data) {

                        var allFmts = _.uniq(_.flatten(_.map(ko.unwrap(data.Movies), function (mov) {
                            return mov.formats();
                        })));
                        _.forEach(allFmts, function (fmt) {
                            var filt = _.findWhere(self.filterFormats, {
                                Id: fmt.Id
                            });
                            if (filt) {
                                filt.enabled(true);
                            }
                        });
                        self.theatre(data);
                    }

                });
        };
        self.changeFormat = function (format) {
            console.log(format);
            self.selectedFormat(format);
            self.movies();

        };


        self.selectedDate.subscribe(function (newVal) {
            self.getPerformances();
        });


        self.getPerformances();

        self.computedMovies = ko.computed(function () {
            var theseMovies = [];
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.movies, function (movie) {
                movie.isActive = ko.observable(false);
                movie.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
                theseMovies.push(movie);
            });
            return theseMovies;
        });
        self.toggleClass = function (sender) {
            sender.isActive(!sender.isActive());


        //      }


        self.toggleHide = function () {

            $('.icon.arrow').click(function () {
                var active_el = $(this);
                $('.movie-listing-header').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).get(0) === active_el.parent().get(0)) {

                        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                            $(this).siblings('.showtimes').hide();
                        } else {
                            $(this).siblings('.showtimes').show();
                        }
                        $(this).toggleClass('active');

                    } else {
                        $(this).removeClass('active');
                        $(this).siblings('.showtimes').hide();
                    }
                });

            });
        }

    }

    window.Regal.TheatreViewModel = TheatreViewModel;
```

the self.computedMovies should return an array that will add some more properties to bind in the markup to help control the css and the style ... I think this will work, but I am getting a hard error in the knockout.debug telling me that my array "self.movies" used in the self.computedMovies is NULL, notice the function is created earlier in the theatreViewModel ... but here is the markup, and the this is the error :

```
 <div data-bind="foreach : {data:movies}">
    <div class="content-item full bottom-border">
    <div class="content-item-container">


         <div data-bind="foreach : computedMovies">
              <div class="movie-listing-header" data-bind="css: { 'active' : isActive()}, click: $parent.toggleClass ">

            <a class="icon arrow"></a>

            <div class="movie-details">
                <div class="title"><a href="#" data-bind="text: MovieName, attr: { href: DetailsUrl }"></a></div> 
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="rating">
                    </div>
                    <div class="time" data-bind=" text: movieruntime "></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="icon right-arrow" href="#" data-bind="attr: { href: DetailsUrl }"></a>


</div>

<div class="showtimes"  data-bind="style: { 'display': isSelected() ? 'block' : 'none' }">    



              <div data-bind="template: { name: 'movie-grouped-showtimes-template', data: $data }"></div>

        </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
   </div>
```

"Uncaught exception error the property "length" is not defined ...

any ideas on how to track this down, I am starting to take other options, but I would like to understand why this is not working, considering the self.movies is used to populate the markup and that IS working.

javascript I am trying to run, after the page is loaded:

```
 $('.icon.arrow').click(function () {
        var active_el = $(this);
        $('.movie-listing-header').each(function () {
            if ($(this).get(0) === active_el.parent().get(0)) {

                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).siblings('.showtimes').hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).siblings('.showtimes').show();
                }
                $(this).toggleClass('active');

            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).siblings('.showtimes').hide();
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The question you're currently asking ("How to track this down?") doesn't have much to do with the actual problem IMO. You basically have two paths:

1. Debug the error as is, using a debugger (e.g. Firebug) with breakpoints, "console.log debugging", etc.
2. Create a reproducible scenario [as small as possible](http://sscce.org/).

The first is the more direct approach and one to try for a short while first. If it fails I'd resort to the second approach. If you have no idea where to start I'd say that [binary search debugging](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50552/how-to-effectively-do-manual-debugging/181223#181223) is a mix of the two.

Once you've found the root cause and/or have a small repro, you probably also have the solution. If not you can post a follow-up SO question with the code to repro the issue (optionally extended with [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)), with a repro it's very likely someone can help you.

Comment: Thank you, I will explore this more today, I just thought that this may have been an issue with knockout.debug as opposed to something I am doing wrong, or I am coding this incorrectly and someone could spot that. I will try to create a scaled version of this, but I didn't write this javascript to begin with and there is alot going on here. but thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck, and be sure to get back and let us know if this approach helped you find/fix things.

Comment: I have added some javascript, this is the code that I am trying to get working, i was told I could use "afterRender" on the my foreach and call a function with this .js in it ... is that possible? and where and how do I set up this function. thanks for any help on this